# why my time shows up in another language than english?

Tags: packages, presentations

I use the following code but the date is written not in english

```
\documentclass[12pt] {beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum} % this is used for the font size
%\usepackage{animate}  % this is for GIF files 
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\tiny}

    \date{\today}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: because you choose German language with `babel` package

Comment: You have specified that the main language of your document is German `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`

Comment: @David Carlisle I tried to change it but it gives me error, it says I am only allowed to use ngerman, is it correct ?

Comment: If you change babel settings you may need to delete your aux file as the previous run will have saved it with German commands.

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes that is for sure, however, if I change it to english now, my outline is gone, are these things logical or is it my computer problem ?

Comment: Compile again and again :)

Comment: That is the whole point of aux files, to record things that take several runs to converge so if you delete it you may need two or three runs of latex to build up all the cross references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

specifies German. Having added it you may need to delete your `aux` file if you remove `babel` or change the language, as language specific settings can get saved in the file.

Comment: I delete it and did like \usepackage[english]{babel}